# Dynamic MySQL recordset query using join syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I can't get the JOIN syntax correct to alter this existing MySQL query in PHP to include a join from another table.  I have another table specified as DB_TABLE2 that contains columns InvmNumr and InvmDesc.  The InvmNumr and InvlNumr are the exact same value in each table and I need to display InvmDesc from Table 2 in this query?

```
        $res = mysql_query('SELECT LocId, InvlNumr, InvlQuant FROM ' . DB_TABLE1
          . ' WHERE LocId = \'' . mysql_real_escape_string($cType) . '\'
        AND InvlNumr = \'' . mysql_real_escape_string($br) . "'");
        $markup = '';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on LEFT JOIN vs INNER JOIN depending on how your data is stored in your `DB_TABLE2` table.

```
$res = mysql_query('SELECT ' . DB_TABLE1 . '.LocId, ' . DB_TABLE1 . '.InvlNumr, ' .
    DB_TABLE1 . '.InvlQuant, ' . DB_TABLE2 . '.InvmDesc 
    FROM ' . DB_TABLE1 . ' LEFT JOIN ' . DB_TABLE2 . ' ON ' . 
    DB_TABLE1 . '.InvlNumr = ' . DB_TABLE2 . '.InvmNumr 
    WHERE ' . DB_TABLE1 . '.LocId = \'' . mysql_real_escape_string($cType) . '\' 
    AND ' . DB_TABLE1 . '.InvlNumr = \'' . mysql_real_escape_string($br) . "'");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT db1.LocId,db1.InvlNumr,db1.InvlQuant
FROM DB_TABLE1  db1
INNER JOIN DB_TABLE2 db2 ON db1.InvlNumr = db2.InvlNumr
WHERE dbq.LocId = $cType
AND db1.InvlNumr = $br
```